# Problems on installing NuGet Package "MvcScaffold" on Visual WebDeveloper 2010 Express

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I got an Exception on trying to install the MvcScaffold NuGet Package on 
Visual WebDeveloper 2010 Express. I am using "ASP.NET MVC 3 Release Candidate" 
(http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/11/09/announcing-the-asp-net-mvc-3-release-candidate.aspx)

Sorry i only can provide the german error message. But the translation should something
like

"Cant bind the argument "Path" cause its NULL On Row:1 ...."

here the original message:

- Install-Package : Das Argument kann nicht an den Parameter "Path" gebunden werden, da es NULL ist.
  Bei Zeile:1 Zeichen:16
- Install-Package <<<<  MvcScaffold

  - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], ParameterBindingValidationException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGet.VisualStudio.Cmdlets.InstallPackageCmdlet

### Thank you all

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error :(

Comment: English error: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.

Comment: FWIW (not much), the problem seems to be isolated to Express.  Following the exact same steps, it works find on Ultimate.  I tweeted this at Scott Hanselman, perhaps he'll figure something out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like its a known item:

> This sounds like a bug in the package. We'll follow up with the package author.

[Link to the NuGet workitem.](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/383)